# How to access a string called "numberPart" from a different file (multithreaded java socket programming)

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

There is a string called `numberPart` inside a thread class called `ServerRecieve`. The location where `.start()` is being called is inside of a different class called `Server`.

The 'numberPart' will eventually be used as a port for file transferring later on.

My question is: How do I access the `numberPart` variable inside of the class called `Server`?

Screenshot of code running (server on left window, client on the right):

[server on left window, client on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2FQ5.png)

In the left window of the screenshot (server) you can see the that the first port number of the right window's command line argument which is `4021` being sent via a text message, and the server successfully receives it with the message `"File transfer port found: 4021"`. Unfortunately this variable is located inside a different class. I would like to know how to access that variable inside the class called `Server`.

ServerRecieve code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerRecieve extends Thread
{

    Socket servSocket;
    boolean m_bRunThread = true; 
    boolean ServerOn = true;

    public ServerRecieve(Socket s) 
    { 
        super(); 
        servSocket = s;
    } 
    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                BufferedReader readFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(servSocket.getInputStream()));
                String fromClient = readFromClient.readLine();
                String a = fromClient;
                int i;
                for(i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
                {
                    char c = a.charAt(i);
                    if( '0' <= c && c <= '9' )
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                String alphaPart = a.substring(0, i);
                String numberPart = a.substring(i);
                System.out.println("Recieved from client: " + alphaPart +"\n");

                System.out.println("File transfer port found: " + numberPart + "\n");
                //String[] filePortNumber = null;
                //filePortNumber[0] = numberPart;
               // Server thing = new Server(filePortNumber);
                if(fromClient.equals(null))
                {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                OutputOptions();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
    }

    void OutputOptions()
    {
        System.out.println("Enter an option ('m', 'f', 'x'): ");
        System.out.println("(M)essage (send)");
        System.out.println("(F)ile (request) ");
        System.out.println("e(X)it ");
    }
}
```

Server source:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.imageio.IIOException;
public class Server
{
    private String[] serverArgs;
    public Socket socket;
    public Socket fileSocket;
    public boolean keepRunning = true;
    public int ConnectOnce = 0;
    public String option = "";
    public boolean isConnected = false;
    public String FILE_TO_SEND = "/Users/nanettegormley/Documents/workspace/assignment2/src/servers/cdm.jpg";

    public Server(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        // set the instance variable

        this.serverArgs = args;
        if(ConnectOnce == 0)
        {
            int port_number1 = Integer.valueOf(serverArgs[1]);
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port_number1);
            socket = serverSocket.accept(); 
            ConnectOnce = 4;
            isConnected = true;

        }

    }
    public String[] serverRun2(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {

        serverArgs = args;
        serverArgs = Arrays.copyOf(args, args.length);
        serverSend.start();
        return serverArgs;
    }

    Thread serverSend = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {   
            OutputOptions();
            while(isConnected)
            {
                try 
                {
                    ServerRecieve serverThread = new ServerRecieve(socket);
                    serverThread.start(); 


                   // input the message from standard input
                   BufferedReader input2= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

                   option = input2.readLine(); 
                   if(option.equals("m") || option.equals("M"))
                   {
                        StandardOutput();
                   }
                   if(option.equals("f") || option.equals("F"))
                   {
                       FileTransferSend();
                   }
                   if(option.equals("x") || option.equals("X"))
                   {
                       System.exit(0);

                   }

               }
               catch ( Exception e )
               {
                   System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
               }
            }
        }
    };


public void StandardOutput()
{
        try
        {           
            //Send the message to the server
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

            //creating message to send from standard input
            String newmessage = "";
            try 
            {
                System.out.println("Enter your message: ");
                // input the message from standard input
                BufferedReader input2= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                String line = "";

                line= input2.readLine(); 
                newmessage += line + " ";

            }
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
                System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
            }
            String sendMessage = newmessage;
            bw.write(sendMessage + "\n");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();
            System.out.println("Message sent to client: "+sendMessage);
            StandardInput();
            //run();
            } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {

            }

}
void FileTransferSend()
{
    //connect to the filetransfer



    try
    {   
        System.out.println("Which file do you want? ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String filename = scanner.nextLine();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(filename));
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fileSocket.getOutputStream()));
        int element;
        while((element = fis.read()) !=1)
        {
            dos.write(element);
        }
        byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[1024]; // buffer

        while(fis.read(byteBuffer)!= -1)
        {
            dos.write(byteBuffer);
        }
        OutputOptions();


       // dos.close();
       // fis.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {

    }
}

void OutputOptions()
{
    System.out.println("Enter an option ('m', 'f', 'x'): ");
    System.out.println("(M)essage (send)");
    System.out.println("(F)ile (request) ");
    System.out.println("e(X)it ");
}


public void StandardInput()
{
    OutputOptions();
    while(true)
    {

        try 
        {
           // input the message from standard input
           BufferedReader input2= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
           String line2 = "";

           option= input2.readLine(); 
           if(option.equals("m") || option.equals("M"))
           {
               StandardOutput();
           }
           if(option.equals("f") || option.equals("F"))
           {
               FileTransferSend();
           }
           if(option.equals("x") || option.equals("X"))
           {
               System.exit(0);

           }

       }
       catch ( Exception e )
       {
           System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
       }
        finally
        {

        }
    }

}




}
```

Full code with all files:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0yq47gapsd3dgjp/folder33.zip?dl=0

My question is: What changes can I make to the code that would allow me to access `numberPart` while being inside `Server`?

EDIT: Is there a way to bump a question that hasn't gotten any answers or should I just delete this one and repost it somewhere?

Comment: Are you sure you posted enough code?  Please explain exactly what trouble you are having

Comment: @ScaryWombat Last time I posted all the code I got downvoted for not being too concise. There's 5 files and here is the link to all the code [https://www.dropbox.com/s/0yq47gapsd3dgjp/folder33.zip?dl=0].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that you could use either a listener or callback pattern to solve this.

(I'm losing my Java memory now that I'm doing C# so please bear with me..)

```
interface PortAssignable {
  public assignPort(int port);
}
```

Then have the Server class implement that interface

```
public Server implements PortAssignable {
...
}
```

And ServerReceive

```
// Constructor
public ServerRecieve(Socket s, PortAssignable portNotifyListener) {
  _portNotifyListener = portNotifyListener;
  ... your other code ...
}
```

Make sure when you create an instance of `ServerReceive`, you pass in your `Server` instance, via `this`.

```
ServerRecieve serverThread = new ServerRecieve(socket, this);
```

Now, when you get your `numberPart`, your next line can be

```
_portNotifyListener.assignPort(numberPart);
```

How you choose to implement the `assignPort` method in your `Server` class is up to you.

**P.S.** *I saw this question from [/r/programming](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming).*

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.

Comment: should the `_portNotifyListener.assignPort(numberPart);` be located inside the `Server` class or the `ServerRecieve` class?

Comment: Inside the ServerReceive class, right after you assign a value to `numberPart`.